# How to write this complex mysql query?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table T that has two columes A & B.

Then I have a big set of data called ARRAY. ARRAY holds a list of data that could appear in A.

I want something below:

1. select top 10 rows order by B DESC, such that row.A is in ARRAY; record the result as R;

2. take rows from R such that row.B > 2/3*max_of_B_in_all_rows

May I do this in one statement? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do it one query (not without a sub-query anyway). Getting max_of_B_in_all_rows can't be done in the context of the rest. This will require two queries -- one to get the max B, and then one to get the rest (or, as I alluded to, max B can be retrieved in a sub-query).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option that uses a [user-defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to store the Max of B:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM (
  SELECT A, B, @maxB:=IF(@maxB>B,@maxB,B) MaxB
  FROM TableT
      JOIN (SELECT @maxB:=0) T2
  WHERE A IN (YourList)
  ORDER BY B DESC
  LIMIT 10
) T
WHERE B >= (2/3)*MaxB
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e962c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest solution in one query with just one join:

```
SELECT *, MAX(B) AS MAXB
FROM T
INNER JOIN ARRAY
USING(A)
ORDER BY B DESC
HAVING B > MAXB * 2 / 3
```